# git diff-files output changes after git status

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a script, `update.py`, that downloads new versions of files tracked in my git repository:

```
$ python update.py
Doing work...
Done
$ git status
On branch my-branch
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   foo.txt
    modified:   bar.txt
    modified:   baz.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Sometimes, the files that are downloaded are identical to the files already in `HEAD`, so after the download the working directory is clean:

```
$ python update.py
Doing work...
Done
$ git status
On branch my-branch
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

However, I've found that `git diff-files` appears to get confused when the files are replaced, even though their contents are identical:

```
$ python update.py
Doing work...
Done
$ git diff-files
:100644 100644 ffa91f655007c56f209cf15fee13c55991a76e18 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M  foo.txt
:100644 100644 dc05558729c3c94a088aa63da3bbd8f1213b8cf3 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M  bar.txt
:100644 100644 002cc3f53dc64b89b1b91adbb6fe61035ba9e832 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M  baz.txt
$ git status
On branch my-branch
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git diff-files
$
```

In the snippet above:

1. I run update.py, which replaces the `foo.txt`, `bar.txt`, and `baz.txt` files with identical copies downloaded from elsewhere.
2. `git diff-files` incorrectly reports that those three files have been edited in-place in the work tree, according to the raw output format described on the [git diff man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).
3. `git status` correctly reports that nothing has changed.
4. `git diff-files`, run after `git status`, now *also* reports that nothing has changed.

After running `update.py`, `git diff-files` will continue to incorrectly report changes until I run `git status`, after which point it behaves again.

What is going on here? Why is `git diff-files` reporting changes when there are none?

---

In case you're curious why this is causing me trouble, here's some more context:

I have another script, `update_and_commit_if_needed.py` that does the following:

1. Run `update.py`.
2. If `git diff-files` returns zero, the working tree is clean, and `update.py` didn't change anything. Exit.
3. Otherwise, the working tree is dirty. Commit the changes.

I was seeing a weird failure in `update_and_commit_if_needed.py`: I'd get to step three, but then `git commit` would complain that there was `nothing to commit, working directory clean`. In tracking down that bug, I discovered this odd behavior of `git diff-files`.

I am using git version 2.5.0 on OS X 10.11.4 (15E65).

---

**EDIT 1:** I've found an easy way to reproduce this behavior:

```
$ git diff-files
$ git status
On branch my-branch
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ cp foo.txt ~
$ mv ~/foo.txt .
$ git diff-files
:100755 100755 20084b5d6da359748f62c259c24f2b9cc2359780 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M  foo.txt
$ git status
On branch my-branch
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git diff-files
$
```

**EDIT 2:** As suggested in a comment, I've tried inverting `core.trustctime` and `core.ignoreStat` from their defaults. This does not appear to change git's behavior in this case.

Comment: Clearly this is some sort of bug.  Exactly what sort... well, that part is *not* clear. :-) Since the index stores `stat` results for cache purposes, your OS may be relevant.  See also the `core.trustctime` and `core.ignoreStat` settings in `git config`.

Comment: Wow, Man! You've just investigated the reasons for a long-standing /misfeature/ of `gitk` which essentially suffers from this bug: sometimes it demonstrates that there're changes but can't demonstrate them, and after  `F5` (reload) the change flag disappears. I'm sure that the quick check involves some kind of `stat` without actual content comparison, but these are only speculations, not real investigations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`git diff-index` does not actually check the contents of files in the working tree. Instead, it uses the stat information of the file and compares it to the index. In fact, the [`diff-index` man page notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index):

> As with other commands of this type, `git diff-index` does not actually look at the contents of the file at all. So maybe `kernel/sched.c` hasn’t actually changed, and it’s just that you touched it. In either case, it’s a note that you need to `git update-index` it to make the index be in sync.

As the note suggests, the index's stat entry can be updated by running `git update-index --refresh` before `diff-files`. The [man page for `update-index` elaborates](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index):

> `--refresh` does not calculate a new sha1 file or bring the index up-to-date for mode/content changes. But what it does do is to "re-match" the stat information of a file with the index, so that you can refresh the index for a file that hasn’t been changed but where the stat entry is out of date.
>
> For example, you’d want to do this after doing a `git read-tree`, to link up the stat index details with the proper files.

Running `update-index --refresh` before `diff-files` erases the symptoms I described, solving the issue.